# QR code scanner

Tags: android, zxing

I would like to create a QR code scanner in my app.

I went through the zxing ,but I could not understand it. I am interested in QR codes only.

All help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Place a copy of the com.google.zxing.client.* source packages into your project.  You can start the zxing scanning activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

In the same activity that you invoked the CaptureActivity in you can handle the result when the scan completes with the following onActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            String response = data.getAction();

            if(Pattern.matches("[0-9]{1,13}", response)) {
                // response is a UPC code, fetch product meta data
                // using Google Products API, Best Buy Remix, etc.          
            } else {
                // QR codes - phone #, url, location, email, etc. 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(response));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where do i need to drop the package ?

Comment: You can copy the ZXing source code right into your project's src directory.

Comment: Under  com.google.zxing.client package there is anothe package - android which contains some classes and packages. It seems like a whole application. Do I need them all in my application or the are some specific classes and packages reqiured for QR scanning? Eyal.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but thought someone might find this useful.

I recently released a qr reader app, and ZXing really is the go-to library on Android. However, I found working with a copy of the source of ZXing project difficult. There is already a library that handles the ZXing core, and even optimizes it for custom usage.

Try [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded):

- Super easy to add to your app.
- Takes care of opening camera in background thread for performance.
- Has docs/examples for custom usage of the scanner.
- Authors respond fast and commit once every 2 weeks :)

I put a guide on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736605/zbar-and-zxing-in-android-studio/31750369#31750369).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There is now an google API for that call [Mobile vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/?hl=en).

Code sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

Answer (score 1):

I did it using a set of plugins, plus I inserted my own additions to make it a 1-stop setup.

1. unzip the attached zip file into your project ( https://github.com/chwagssd/qr/archive/master.zip )
2. point to <script src="path/to/decoder.js"><script>
3. Create a file input in your HTML page that has an id, say "xxx"

   ```
   <input type="file" id="xxxx">
   ```
4. Then tell the page on load to QRIfy your field! Make sure to include your callback function, which will be called with a single argument (the FULL TEXT that was scanned): QRIfy('qrCode', onQrCode);//where qrCode is the id of your

   ```
   <input type="file" id="xxxx">
   ```

I have setup a GIT repo here, grab the code (you can download the zip and put it in your javascript folder)

https://github.com/chwagssd/qr

Comment: Guess I was too late on this one! This question is so 2011 :)