# How to Scan QR Code in android

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to read QR code in a text, how can I do this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: see this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAvFiQ_POMg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is really broad and can't be answered within a single answer here *(e.g. you could use a library, see blessenm's comment; or you could write everything from scratch, which involves image processing and so on)*. This means it's not a good fit for StackOverflow. Please have a look at [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for more info what you can ask here and what not - and which details you should include in your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks So much for replying..and Your guidance,but in my application I have to read this QR code and store it into the sqlite database.and Zxing is very huge how can i include it.

Comment: Which library I have to use for that and please give me basic starting for this I am totaly new..so dont have any Idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [QR code scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498051/qr-code-scanner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your talking about how to reading and not development you can download a free QR reader from the market and use it.

If your programming then i also suggest using ZXing project lib to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to seek guidance from ZXing's project, as mentioned below your question by blessenm. Once you get the code. You need to setup that code and run that on your device. Explore this code and get the basics. I hope it will be lot easier for you to understands how it works. You can simplify that code eliminating extra things.